# How to force DataGridView cell validation before closing form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I can edit. After editing, and when I click Enter or select another cell, `CellValueChanged` event occurs and I save this new value.

My problem : If I change cell value and close form without click Enter or select another cell before, this last value isn't saved.

Is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270826/3110834

Comment: What is your data source? For example for a data set https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797309/3110834

Comment: @RezaAghaei I think it works but how to activate `CellValueChanged` or `CellValidating` event before closing ?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Hmm sorry it works perfectly ! (`dataGridView.EndEdit();`) Thank you :)

Comment: `DataGridView.EndEdit` will not raise the validations which you have in `CellValidating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `DataTable` as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`, then use the following code to validate and end edit:

```
this.Validate();
dataGridView1.BindingContext[yourDatTable].EndCurrentEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first how the "CellValueChanged" event works. i think in you case when you close the form the event isnt triggered. What i would do is when you close Form the event "FormClosing" is triggered and it calls a method("SaveThisNewValue()") that saves your value. The method for saving your values is also used in "cellValueChanged" event

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveThisNewValue();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveThisNewValue();
    }

    private void SaveThisNewValue()
    {
        //saves the cell value
    }
```

Comment: I already thought about this solution but is there not a way to forced a verification of this last cell selected ? Or just a forced validation of this cell ?

Answer (score 0):

grid.EndEdit() worked for me in the form closing event.