# How to update changes in the data source after changing the cell value in the dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

The user makes changes to the cell.
The `CellEndEdit` event is triggered.
In the `Save ()` method, changes are displayed in the `adapter.Update (table_2);` line.
Changes are not displayed in the database (changes are not saved to the database).
 
If the user calls the `Save ()` method using the button, the changes are displayed in the database (in the data source table `dataGridView`).
 
**Question.**
How to update changes in the data source after changing the cell value in the dataGridView?

**My Code**

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            Save();
            richTextBox1.Text += i + " Event - `CellEndEdit` \r\n";
        }


     public DataTable CreateCmds()
            {
                table_2 = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=True";              

                    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                        connection.Open();

                        adapter.Fill(table_2);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    string s = ex.Message;
                    string t = ex.StackTrace;
                    // throw;
                }

                return table_2;
            }

            public void Save()
            {
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=True";

                string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                    connection.Open();

                    adapter.Update(table_2);
                }
            }
```

[image]

**Update_1**
The same thing happens when I use the `CellValueChanged` event.
The `CellValueChanged` event is triggered.
In the `Save ()` method, changes are displayed in the `adapter.Update (table_2);` line.
Changes are not displayed in the database (changes are not saved to the database).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            Save();
            richTextBox1.Text += i + " Event - `CellValueChanged` \r\n";
        }
```

Comment: You're not actually saving anything in the database with your `Save()` method, you're just running another view query. You need to change your querystring in something like "UPDATE SET myField = myValue WHERE (SELECT clause)" or, better for security reasons, a stored procedure name with parameters.

Comment: @Davide Vitali Why when I call the `Save () method using the button, the changes are saved in the database?

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood the situation. The problem is the event you used, you need `CellValueChanged` and not `CellEndEdit`, because the latter is used in case of errors in validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the `CellEndEdit`:

> Occurs when edit mode stops for the currently selected cell.

and follows an example on how to catch this event triggering in case of misvalidation - that's why it stops: not because the user has finished, but because a validation event occurred. On the other side, [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the `CellValueChanged` says that

> The DataGridView.CellValueChanged event occurs when the user-specified value is committed, which typically occurs when focus leaves the cell.

which is your case. Cheers!

Comment: Updated the question.
Update_1

Comment: @eusataf Shouldn’t the update argument be of DataSet type instead of DataTable?

Comment: @eusataf The `CellValueChanged` is a valid solution. You most likely are making a mistake somewhere else. For example may pass a wrong instance of the datatable to update method, while editing another instance.

Comment: @RezaAghaei How to track and fix it?

Comment: @eusataf You probably are missing `EndCurrentEdit` of the `BindingContext`. You will find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811458/3110834) useful.

Comment: @DavideVitali You may want to add a note to the answer. For some data sources like `DataTable` you need it, while for some data sources for example binding to a `List<T>` you don't need it.